# Geolocation API not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation, weather

I am building a weather page and I need to grab the user location in order to get the weather data.

```
if ((navigator.geolocation)&&(location!=null)) {
    var locations = null;
    window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
        var latitude  = position.coords.latitude;
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        locations = latitude+'/'+longitude;
        show_all_weather_components();  
        console.log("1");
    }); 
}
/* If location is not found the set default location as USDC0001, which is default code for washington DC. */

var locations= !locations?"USDC0001":locations;
console.log("2");
```

I am getting 2 first in my console. ie. It is always setting default address rather than the user actual address. I know it sounds ridiculous but is there some way to avoid the "non-blocking" mode of the code here.
Or is there some other way to grab the user location. I tried the ip database Api as well, but it didn't worked with precision.

At one point I thought of to put a delay just below the if condition part, but Due to different modules of this weather app, my page is already very slow. Any Idea will be appreciated. 
Thank you

Comment: locations variable always null so if condition fails

Comment: navigator.geolocation is not a Jquery part, but of HTML 5. Also it prompt the user to share location on page load. Until the user shares it, you won't be able to get the user location on user.

Comment: I get that, even if I have previously allowed to share the location, it is taking time and the console.log("2") is executing earlier than console.log("1).

Comment: Ok I will try to take the var location =null out, and check

Comment: Still not working. same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the other arguments of getCurrentPosition. Here is an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="result"></div>
  <script>
     var result = document.getElementById('result');
     if (navigator.geolocation && location != null) {        
       window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
         result.text = position.coords.latitude + '/' + position.coords.longitude;
       }, function(error) {           
         switch(error.code) {
           case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
             result.innerHTML = "Denied request for Geolocation."
             break;
           case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
             result.innerHTML = "Location unavailable."
             break;
          case error.TIMEOUT:
             result.innerHTML = "Location request timed out." 
             break;
          case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
             result.innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred."
             break;
         }
       }, { timeout: 1000, maximumAge: 1000 }); 
     }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, Any thing that was missing was the third parameter.